# Trying to upgrade RHEL 6.10 - yum errors - how to proceed

Tags: redhat, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade a Redhat 6.10 box to 7. It's a web hosting box. I have been unable to update it in a while and so as expected, upgrading wouldn't be as easy as it should be.

I tried `yum upgrade` and received the following: https://pastebin.com/ZcGLWdGg

Is this a bad idea altogether or is it just a matter of trial and error and upgrading is just a long process given the situation?

Comment: Contact cPanel support for this. We won't be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

- [Read the RHEL 7 documentation on upgrading.](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/migration_planning_guide/chap-Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-Migration_Planning_Guide-Upgrading)
- Plan your upgrade.
- Execute it on a test system.

More than just a yum upgrade is required for a relatively easy upgrade from EL 6 to 7. Use `preupg` to prep then `redhat-upgrade-tool` to execute the upgrade.

(Should work on EL distros like CentOS as well, but I'm not finding documentation that a CentOS `preupgrade-assistant` package exists and functions.)

---

Some choose to skip the in-place upgrade, clean install the next version, and migrate data. Ideally, either in-place upgrade or clean install are possible, but in reality either has their challenges.

Comment: He's running cPanel. I'm pretty sure it will blow up spectacularly regardless of which route he takes, without specialized support from them, and possibly even with.

Comment: Thanks - I decided to spin up an adjacent RHEL7 box, install appropriate packages, then migrate files as necessary and test.

Answer (score 0):

Root cause appears to be here:

`Error: Package: rpm-4.8.0-59.el6.x86_64 (@rhel-6-server-rpms)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-22.el6.x86_64 (@rhel-x86_64-server-6)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
               Not found`

As you can see frmo that, you have a rhel-6-server package that has been obsoleted by another package installed by EPEL. Check /etc/yum.repos.d/ and see if you have EPEL available at all; it may be that it's even for the next major version up (7).

I believe you could run `yum remove libdb4`, disable the EPEL if it's anywhere, and then re-install using just the rhel-6 repos.

Regardless, it appears there's some version discrepancies between installed packages and currently enabled repos, and that's the problem - I say that because your pastebin appears to show only rhel6 repos currently enabled:

`Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, security, subscription-
              : manager, universal-hooks
Setting up Update Process
rhel-6-server-optional-rpms                           | 2.0 kB     00:00

rhel-6-server-rpms                                    | 2.0 kB     00:00

rhel-6-server-supplementary-rpms                      | 2.0 kB     00:00`

Comment: -rw-r--r--   1 root root   244 Feb  7 05:55 cPAddons.repo
-rw-------   1 root root   239 Nov  7  2018 cpanel-plugins.repo
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   957 May 11 10:48 epel.repo
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1056 Nov 25  2014 epel-testing.repo
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  8446 May 11 10:38 redhat.repo
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   529 May 21  2018 rhel-source.repo

Comment: How do I enable RH7 repos or the repos needed?

Comment: Yes, you can see there that at some point the EPEL has been added, though based on the previous snippet doesn't appear to be active currently. That will be the root problem.

Comment: You'll have to proceed very carefully. EPEL

Comment: Submitted too soon - EPEL will complicate things. I have never had real success doing an in-place upgrade so I'm not too sure - typically I spin up an adjacent RHEL7 box, install appropriate packages, then migrate files as necessary and test.

Comment: Sounds like what I have to do. Thanks for the help!